# Forcing a fingerprint authentication using MSAL or ADAL

Tags: authentication, xamarin, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

So I have an Azure Active Directory app registration for my Xamarin mobile app that allows a user to authenticate with AAD and do things like show their profile information.  All is well.

What I am looking to do is force the user to re-authenticate with a fingerprint (if available) on-demand.  Much like how the Outlook for Android app authenticates me all the time, asking for a fingerprint, how do I do that?  Is this a feature or ADAL, MSAL, Microsoft Authenticator, or something else?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I came across this question as I'm trying to figure it out myself. But after pondering the concept of MSAL vs fingerprint, I realised it's probably not possible. Because MSAL is an external auth provider, whereas fingerprint match is locally determined on the device.

Comment: @StevenManuel how about you, did you solve this?